# catch error from reject method of promise

Tags: javascript

I have the following code which returns an 'uncaught (in promise) object' error in the console when the ajax call fails.

```
const customCall = (requestType, submitUrl, values) =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    $.ajax({
      type: requestType,
      url: submitUrl,
      dataType: 'json',
      data: values,
      success: response => resolve(response),
      error: err => reject(err),
    });
  }).catch((err) => {
    const errorObject = { _error: "fail" };
    throw errorObject;
  }).then((result)=> { //do whatever }) ;
```

why can't i catch this error ?

Comment: You already caught the error, then you threw an object.

Comment: Let's try return $.ajax({ inside your promise